# Change background colour of button for Django image upload field

Tags: html, css, django, button

I have the following field in one of my forms to allow the user to upload an image in Django:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, null=True, blank=True)
```

I display it as a field in my form table as follows:

```
<form method='POST' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
    <div style="overflow-x:auto;">
        <table class="table-form" style='table-layout:fixed;'>
            <tr>
              <th>Image</th>
              <td>{{ form.image }}</td>
            </tr>
            ...
```

And here is what the HTML of the image field looks like when I inspect the element with Chrome Developer Tools:

```
<input id="id_image" name="image" type="file">
```

I am trying to change the button background colour, and text "No File Chosen" size to it is smaller than the button text.

[image]

Currently I can only change both at once with the following in my css:

```
#id_image {
 background-color: orange;
}
```

[image: Eurgh]

How do I assign css to the button and text next to it separately? Help! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add a `label` and get the filename with JavaScript.

Then change the css of your label as you wish.

This will help you :

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/uqgkaubv/)